# WPF SQLite EF "No such table" if run application from startup of shell

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, windows-10

I have the strange problem. I use SQLite with EF in my WPF application. If the application run via double click of mouse on exe file all works fine. But when I try to start the application via Windows autorun or instead explorer.exe I get exception with "No such [tableName] table" message when I try to get list of users from database. If I run the application manually all works fine.

What is the difference between autorun(or instead explorer.exe) and manually run?

***Added***

**Cause:** Loris156: I think you are using a relative path and the application working directories are different. Check your directory using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). An application in Autorun will have a different directory

**Solution:** I checked it. In "autorun mode" application have C:\Windows\system32 path.

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) is solves this problem.

Comment: I think you are using a relative path and the application working directories are different. Check your directory using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. An application in Autorun will have a different directory.

Comment: @Loris156, you are absolutely right! I checked it. In "autorun mode" application have C:\Windows\system32 path. hmmm... First thing how to fix it is finding application install directory from code. But I guess that it's not good solution...

Comment: Data for applications should never be stored in the installation directory, use AppData or My Documents for example.